# How to generate a short token with laravel passport?

Tags: php, laravel, access-token, laravel-passport

I am using laravel passport with password grant mode , i found  it generated access token is very  long , like this :

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 31536000,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjRmOTlkNDI2ZmIxN2I5OGVmNzExYzMyOGQ2YzMwODBhOGY4OGVjYWI4Yjg3Zjg2MmFkNWFlNGI5MzdiYjg0MGQ3MDk2NWI2OWY4NDk3MTE0In0.eyJhdWQiOiIyIiwianRpIjoiNGY5OWQ0MjZmYjE3Yjk4ZWY3MTFjMzI4ZDZjMzA4MGE4Zjg4ZWNhYjhiODdmODYyYWQ1YWU0YjkzN2JiODQwZDcwOTY1YjY5Zjg0OTcxMTQiLCJpYXQiOjE0ODk0NDAzODEsIm5iZiI6MTQ4OTQ0MDM4MSwiZXhwIjoxNTIwOTc2MzgxLCJzdWIiOiIyIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.XEY0vMoUt6Z9cWMkELQhfcaC2uab8odQLmIVTh8YWULSYOPuw4vpTDFurgU2vflM8-5PYuIIOnw8-8CQVZvetkYLpp2r0GqdNPIcCwlZNh9zRFLLigJ1vm4GKsbGozoDieR9FBpvQ2K9gFM0V4kwjSwx74fdlC1imC1rZ8qRYy5e1zctrMSrVcGcT5F4PTm4DdTN50IRcsOIJK9T6Wgec-iYmey0-xKg0UQroCF6rZUtC0VlH8XwhW_1QfrCl7dkKIcEbWi4pgzDpwrLMZgLAQpPktCP2G9SujC99e7M_L3C8Y647enwUQSTKtp6xNyTyyHSqS0NAxU4U0TFTICMPH5D_L_WaTeBCLS3MdwM3cmTQdkjdXjljjurHld3yEvVemo7oAr2Wb_HOC1uFET0ndeVGI1ZhgM-AuUBy1dJrV4a0iyUIiVtO12LadFIK2m9h0YQlawN1me_HQy6FxdBQuMJ3WIuR3Mwp79RHkoYKFQGvfxTTK8N0emZzmLl5rODp6n7I1UKDb_g7weHdmFP2paTJCApikIXidYA-QXa1i2qMfCwB7gF_kqBvrOyL29wFFRBc_ACRA-0I8iEhZ18vF7htKkPgWoYyPzBKHjVJ4vrxV_VxbGcszIC5byAJKcmpcXEOnFXkFV7NF-tOb___hw9THTjYQmznM1OS__U8zA",
    "refresh_token": "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"
}
```

I know  a long token  will be safer, but over one thousand characters seems a bit scary.  In my impression, JWT  is  commonly very small, but here,  this generated token is so long, so big .

I want to generate a shorter token , what is good way to do it?

If laravel passport  is able to specify lenght of token?

Comment: I think those are standard OAUTH tokens, which per definition can be 255 characters long - it is also a security measure to use a sufficiently long one. What are your reasons against a long token?

Comment: @MyronHöster the access token in the post is over a thousand characters long, though.

Comment: Yeah over 1000 characters seems wrong to me too.. try reading the docs about geenrating tokens https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having a similar issue where the token is over 1000 characters long!

Comment: Same problem here. 

Comment: Anyone could resolve this? Same problem!

Answer (score 4):

If you feel need to shorten the token length, maybe you should regenerate the key pair files with this command:

```
php artisan  passport:keys  --length=512 --force
```

Comment: it gives error "The "--length" option does not exist." when i run the command

Answer (score 3):

The length of the JWT depends on 2 things: your payload size and the encryption algorithm used. Laravel appears to be using public/private key hashing (RS256) for their JWTs, which requires longer key lengths than say using HS256 algorithm. You can see it if you go to https://jwt.io/ and paste in your token.

If you want to use Laravel Passport then there is no easy way around this length requirement. You can either create libs with methods that override the Passport method used to set the hashing algorithm (not recommended that you go down this rabbit hole), or you can just not use Passport and instead implement your own JWT token authentication system, or you can just live with the long tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Using Passport version less than `"^7.0.0"` the JTI (id of token saved in `oauth_access_tokens` table) is in the header as well as in the body of the JWT. Upgrading to version `"^8.0.0"` can reduce the JWT token with another 100 bytes or so because they removed the JTI from the header.

So combining the upgrade to version 8 and the [answer by Sreng-s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56729617/4232765), my JWT is down to 340 bytes. It's better than the 1070 bytes I started out with but it's still really big considering it's being sent with every request.

Any further improvements would be very much appreciated.