# Short Bearer token

Tags: php, laravel, bearer-token

How can I reduce the length of the Bearer token of PHP Laravel?

The smallest I have found is 512 bit using

```
php artisan passport:key --force
```

But I need 255.

How can it be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a short token with laravel passport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765671/how-to-generate-a-short-token-with-laravel-passport)

Comment: I'm not sure passport is appropriate for your requirement. Maybe a simple token authentication using the [TokenGuard](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php) works better for you. However the setup for that is rather manual [see this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards)

Comment: Have a look at Sanctum. It's a bit simpler than Passport. I don't know your other requirements. But have a look at it.